# ./configure error for gmp-6.1.2 on cygwin64

Tags: configuration, cygwin, gmp

```
$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=64
checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 ... no
checking compiler cc -O ... no
checking ABI=x32
checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mx32 ... no
checking compiler cc  ... no
checking ABI=32
checking compiler gcc -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler icc -no-gcc ... no
checking compiler cc -O ... no
```

### configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

So I investigated that cc exists:

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/cc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 MeTheUser Domain Users 7 Jan  3 17:52 /usr/bin/cc -> gcc.exe
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ ls  -al /usr/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 3 MeTheUser Domain Users 876051 Nov 13 14:39 /usr/bin/gcc
```

---

What should I look for in config.log ?

Comment: If gcc -m32 works at all on cygwin64, it will require that both 64-bit and 32-bit gcc are installed.  At a minimum, gcc -m32 -v would work.  I haven't seen a minimal configure of gmp on cygwin64 even try to build both 64- and 32-bit libraries so I doubt its a commonly desired feature.  You would look for the test case which is used and try those various compile commands, see what are the error messages.  Also, you could compare what you are using with the setup for gmp in the cygwin sources, although it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: configure tried to compile a test program using gcc, and that failed (hence the "no"). You want to find the corresponding error message in the log.

Comment: cygwin64 already has `gmp-6.1.2`. Install `libgmp-devel` for the development package. If you want to look how the package is built, look at the cygwin source package